# How can I persist my form selections so I can use them later?

Tags: javascript, php

I have a page that consists of 3 drop down lists: Agency Network, Agency Name and Customer Name. When the user selects the Network, it is used in the query to create the agency dropdown. When the user selects the Agency, it is used int eh query to create the customer dropdown. Creating the dropdowns appear to be working fine, thanks to some help I received here the other day. My problem now is persisting the selections so that I can create a query based on the network, agency and customer.

Here's my current code.

```
   if (!isset($_POST['network'])){
    echo "Form error";
   } else
   {
   $message = "form was successfully submitted";
   //echo "{$message} <br />";   
   $network = $_POST['network'];
   // echo "<br /> the network is :{$network}";
   // echo "<br />";

   }
   ?>
   <?php
   //**********************************************
   // query DB for NETWORK list
   //**********************************************
   $net = "";
   $agency = "";
   $query = "SELECT network_id, network_code FROM pps_agency_network";
   $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
   // create the html for the drop down menu for NETWORK

   echo "<body>";
   echo "<div id='network_name' class='col-md-3'>";
   echo "<h2> Agency Network </h2>";
   echo "<form action='droplistpop6b.php' method='post'>";
   echo "<select name='network'>";
   echo '<option value="*">ALL</option>';
   while($result1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   // Populate the network dropdown list    

              unset($network_id, $network_name);
              $network_id = $result1['network_id'];
              $network_name = $result1['network_code']; 
              echo $network_name;
              echo '<option 
   value="'.$network_id.'">'.$network_name.'</option>';
   }
   echo "</select>";

   // send the value that was selected from the dropdown list
   echo "<input name='submit' type='submit' value='Send' />";
   //echo "</form>";
   echo "</div>";

   if(!isset($_POST['network'])){
    //echo "network key was not set <br />";
    } else  {   

    $net = $_POST['network'];
    ?>
```

The $net variable contains the value that was selected for network. In the code snippet below, I am trying to save this value to local storage in Javascript. However, it does not appear to be working

```
   <script>
    // ADDED JAVASCRIPT TO SAVE TO LOCAL STORAGE
    window.onload = function() {
    var net = "<?php echo $net ?>"; // "A string here"  
    if (localStorage) {

            // Save the contents of net in locaStorage
            localStorage.setItem('net', net);
            alert("net is" + net);

        });
      else {
        // local storage not supported
        alert "local storage not supported";
       }
      }
      </script>
```

Comment: Saving isn't enough, where's the code that reads from `localStorage` and sets the dropdowns accordingly?

Comment: The code that sets the drop downs is contained in the code above. See the section commented: Query DB for Network list. Here a DB query is done and the results are fetched from associative array and populate the select element. The form is submitted here                                        
      ' echo "<input name='submit' type='submit' value='Send' />";'

Comment: and I retrieve the post data using                                                                          
    '$net = $_POST['network'];'

Comment: Then, I was attempting to save the contents of $net to local storage and read it later. Is this the best approach? Is there another, better approach for storing and accessing this variable later?

Comment: We're talking past each other. If you want to store the user's dropdown selection on the client/browser, you have to use localStorage. I see JavaScript code that *stores* the info, but I don't see JavaScript code that *loads* it and sets the dropdown to the appropriate selection. All I see is PHP code that *populates* the dropdown.

Comment: I added code to save value in local storage and then read from local storage. I am running this code in WAMP and using localhost with IE as browser. When I retrieve the value from local storage, I do a console.log of that value but nothing show up.

Comment: I uses these statements to save the value and then console.log a message afterwards  `  '<script>
  // ADDED CODE to pass PHP variable to JAVASCRIPT AND TO SAVE IN LOCAL STORAGE 
  window.onload = function() {
  // pass the PHP variable $net to Javascript variable net 
  var net = "<?php echo $net ?>"; 
  if (localStorage) {
   
    alert("local storage supported");
    // Save the contents of net to locaStorage
    localStorage.setItem('net', net);
    console.log("local storage here");
   
   });' `

Comment: I am new to SO so I'm not sure what I do to add add'l code to comments so that it is formatted. . Anyway, I added the following code to read from local storage

Comment: `<script>
  // ADDED JAVASCRIPT TO READ SAVED VALUE 
  window.onload = function() {
  // pass the PHP variable $net to Javascript variable net 
  var net = "<?php echo $net ?>"; 
  // READ from local storage and pass to PHP
  if (localStorage) {
   
    alert("local storage supported");
    // read the contents of net from  localStorage
    var netparm = localStorage.getItem('net');
    
    // pass Javascript variable to PHP need to ADD this
    
    
    console.log("local storage here");`

Comment: The console.log statements are not displaying any output.

Comment: `window.onload = ...` is a bad way of setting that event, because if you do that twice, only the second function will run. You're already using `window.onload = ...` for the save code, so my guess is you're overwriting either the load or the save code, depending on what's first in your script. The proper way is `window.addEventListener("load", function () { ... });`